# Ylim max to change dynamically with a variable, while min is set to 0 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my graphs to start at y= 0, but I would like the maximum to change with a multiple of the data, or somehow otherwise zoom out dynamically. I have 34 charts in this set with various ymax.

I have tried `scale_y_continuous` and `coord_cartesian` but when I try to put in the `expand = expand_scale(mult = 2)` that works for getting my maximum to change dynamically, but then the graphs start to start at negative numbers, and I want them to start at 0.

```
title<- c( 
  "Carangidae",
  "Atlantic cutlassfish",
  "Lizardfish",
  "Sharks",
  "Mackerel")
```

```
#DATA#
biomass<- structure(list(timestep = structure(c(10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 
11078, 11109, 11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292), class = "Date"), 
    bio_pre_Carangidae = c(0.01105, 0.0199, 0.017, 
    0.01018, 0.0119, 0.0101, 0.009874, 0.009507, 
    0.009019, 0.00843, 0.00841, 0.00805), bio_obs_Carangidae = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.00239, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), bio_pre_Atl_cutlassfish = c(0.078, 
    0.069, 0.067, 0.06872, 0.0729, 0.0769, 
    0.0775, 0.075, 0.0743, 0.072, 0.071, 
    0.069), bio_obs_Atl_cutlassfish = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.0325, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), bio_pre_lizardfish = c(0.0635, 
    0.062, 0.057, 0.0536, 0.0505, 0.0604, 
    0.0627, 0.068, 0.0695, 0.066, 0.0623, 
    0.0598), bio_obs_lizardfish = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.037, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), bio_pre_sharks = c(0.025, 0.0155, 
    0.0148, 0.0135, 0.01379, 0.01398, 0.014, 
    0.0139, 0.0136, 0.0132, 0.0126, 0.011), 
    bio_obs_sharks = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.003, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), bio_pre_mackerel = c(0.0567, 0.0459, 
    0.0384, 0.03, 0.0328, 0.0336, 0.0299, 
    0.0296, 0.02343, 0.02713, 0.0239, 0.019
    ), bio_obs_mackerel = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.055, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

This is my function:

```
function (biomass, .var1, .var2, .var3) {
    p <- ggplot(biomass, aes(x = timestep)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = .data[[.var1]], linetype = "Predicted")) + geom_point(size = 3, aes(y = .data[[.var2]], shape = "Observed")) + 
ggtitle(paste0(.var3)) + 
ylab(expression("biomass" ~ (t/km^2))) + 
theme_classic() + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = expand_scale(mult = 2))+

  ###This is the portion where I cannot figure out how to set ymin = 0 and then ymax to 2* the maximum value of a dataset.##

theme(legend.position = "right") + 
theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1), axis.ticks.length = unit(0.25, "cm"))
    return(p)
} 


## create two separate name vectors
var1_names <- colnames(biomass)[grepl("^bio_pre", colnames(biomass))]
var2_names <- colnames(biomass)[grepl("^bio_obs", colnames(biomass))]
var3_names <- title

## loop through two vectors simultaneously and save result in a list 
# ..1 = var1_names, ..2 = var2_names
my_plot_b <- pmap(list(var1_names, var2_names, var3_names), ~ my_bio_plot(biomass, ..1, ..2, ..3))

## merge plots together
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/
# install.packages("cowplot", dependencies = TRUE)
dev.new(title = "Model Fit Biomass",
        width = 12,
        height = 6,
        noRStudioGD = TRUE
)
print(my_plot_b)
```

I can manage to get EITHER a set ymin=0 (a) OR a dynamic ymax (b) but cannot manage to get both.

a

[image]

b

[image]

Comment: You should take a look at `facet_wrap` - would make this plot much easier

Comment: thanks, I couldnt figure out how to do that without making changes to my dataset. This was also a useful function that transferred to other plots I needed to generate - (i have over 100 to generate, and the dataframes are not standard between them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Seems to work on your data.

Define the max for each chart at the top of your function:

```
my_bio_plot <-  function (biomass, .var1, .var2, .var3) {
  max_y = 2.0 * max(biomass[[.var1]]) 
  ...
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max_y)) +
  ...
```

This seems to create the requested output, with min y = 0 and max y = 2 * max y in data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does not seem to be giving me the results I'm looking for: I am getting figure a above instead of figure b with a 0 limit. or if I change to 
```max_y = 2.0 * max(.data[[.var1]]) ``` i just get blank graphs.

Comment: I think I got this to work now. Instead of  using ```scale_y_continuous``` I used ```coord_cartesian```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to add a substantially different approach from yours:

```
biomass %>% 
  gather(species, bio, -timestep) %>% 
  mutate(type = ifelse(stringr::str_detect(species, 'pre'), 'predicted', 'observed'),
         species = gsub(".*_", "", species)) %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  mutate(ul = max(bio, na.rm = TRUE) * 2) %>% 
  filter(species == "sharks") -> df

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(timestep, bio, group = type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type)) +
  # facet_wrap(~species) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "", 
                        values = c("blank", 'solid')) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", 
                        values = c(19, NA))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(df$ul)))
```

You could remove the `filter(species == "sharks") and uncomment the`facet_wrap(~species) and you will get all the species plotted at the same time.

Comment: Right, but I want to manipulate that ymax to be 2* the maximum value of my data. using expand_limits is how I got figure a but I want a more zoomed out view.